# CRA and bundle-loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, react-router, eslint, create-react-app

I am trying to use `react-router` with [code splitting](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/code-splitting) inside my `create-react-app` application.

```
import loadSettings from 'bundle-loader?lazy!./Settings';
```

This line gets my an error:

```
 Line 5:  Unexpected '!' in 'bundle-loader?lazy!./Settings'. Do not use import syntax to configure webpack loaders  import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
```

I assume this is because of some `es-lint` settings. How can I disable it so I can use webpack `bundle-loader` inside my CRA application?

Answer (score 1):

I somehow managed to solve this.
What I did is:

1. Eject the `creact-react-app` by running `npm run eject`
2. Modify the `package.json` file by adding a `rules` key to the `eslintConfig` so it looks like this:

   ```
   "eslintConfig": {
       "extends": "react-app", // This was already in the file
       "rules": {
           "import/no-webpack-loader-syntax": 0
       }
   }
   ```
3. Set your components like described in the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/code-splitting.md).

Hope this helps someone, as I have digged through many forums without finding the right answer!

BTW support for code splitting with dynamic import should be coming to `CRA` soon!